# Creating an array that only contains the letters from a string

Tags: arrays, regex, ruby, string

So I'm trying to change the string `\t\n` into an array of all of word characters in the string. The array I want would look like this: `["t","n"]`.

So far I've tried:

```
input = " \t\n"
array = input.scan(/\w/)
```

I've tried this regular expression on this string on rubular and it matches with all of the word characters as I'd like it to.

However, when using `input.scan(/\w)` an empty array is returned.

Please forgive my ignorance as I'm still new to this, but why is this?

Comment: `" \t\n"` has no letters in it. It is a sequence of a space, tab and newline chars.

Comment: Try `puts " \t\n"` and count the letters you see in the output yourself. How many are there? =)

Comment: `"t"` and `"\t"` are not the same thing. One is the letter `"t"` and the other is a [tab character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key#Tab_characters).

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings#Escape_sequences

Comment: You can use `String#dump` though to convert the characters.  Check out my answer.

Comment: Do you want something like the following? `h = { "\t"=>"t", "\n"=>"n" }; "\tMy dog has\nfleas".gsub(/[\t\n]/, h) #=> "tMy dog hasnfleas"`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go!  You were really close.

```
input = " \t\n"
array = input.dump.scan(/\w/)

=> ["t", "n"]
```

The key is to use `String#dump` (see: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/String.html#method-i-dump)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with ruby but you seem to be having string interpolation confusion.

Per https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/new-line-in-string/176797

```
input = " \t\n"
```

Gives you a string with a space, tab, and newline.

You probably want to use single quotes to literally get the string you wrote:

```
input = ' \t\n'
```

If you sorely want to stick with double-quotes then I believe this would work:

```
input = " \\t\\n"
```

---

You should read https://blog.appsignal.com/2016/12/21/ruby-magic-escaping-in-ruby.html to learn more about string interpolation in Ruby. I would link you to the official docs but my lack of ruby experience translates to a lack of official doc experience.

Answer (score 0):

So like colleagues explain in comments, the letters which you have in `"\t\n"` string are not ordinary letters, only something called `special characters` so I am not sure but there is not easy way to take this characters from this string cause `\t` is like one character.

With normal string like `tn` you could do something like this

```rb
"tn".split("")
```

and that give you array which you want.

But on special characters like in the example. you could do something like this

```rb
a = "\t\n".split("")

a.map! do |e|
  if e == "\t"
    "t"
  elsif e == "\n"
    "n"
  end
end
```

which give you, I believe, results which you want.